# Combine while and if statement in bash

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, while-loop

Let's say I have a file `file.txt` that contains the following lines:

```
cat
dog
fish
emu
```

I can get the content of the files with `sed -n ip` where `i` is a whole number corresponding with the line number. Let's call each line `var`.

Now, I'd like to use each line to see if it matches a line in another file `match.txt` similar to `file.txt`.

The contents of `match.txt` is something like this:

```
cat.food.something.more.1010.stuff
dog.more.something.stuff.1010.sometihng
emu.something.carrot.whatever
```

The `if`statement goes like this:

```
if [[ -n $(grep -i $var /some/directory/match.txt | grep food | grep something | grep whatever ) ]]; then
    echo "$var matches"
else
    echo "$var" does not match"
fi
```

The grep'ing in the `if` statement basically strips down the string in `match.txt` to the first word. It's basically checking whether or not it returns something after the grep is applied.

How can I combine the two functions in bash? In short, I'd like to check if each line in a file matches the lines in another file.

Update:

What I want:

1. `file.txt` have a string on each line
2. `match.txt` have strings that, with grep, maybe will match a line in `file.txt`
3. The grep filter is always the same (for now)
4. `file.txt` have an unknown number of lines
5. I'd like to check **all** the lines in `file.txt` if the match the lines in `match.txt`, after the lines in `match.txt` have been processed with grep.
6. If some lines match, echo it out
7. In the future have more than one `match.txt` and search those as well, and echo out which `match.txt`-file the match came from (so join isn't an option)

Comment: The if statement makes no sense. Please, try to reformulate.

Comment: @choroba it's a bit complicated, but basically if the grep'ing returns a result, it's a match, and otherwise it's not a match. Updated the question.

Comment: Paraphrasing your comment: "Posing the problem in an abstract way is complicated." Please try to refrain from abstractions and post `file.txt`, `match.txt`, and what you expect to receive. We might be able to help.

Comment: @joepd I don't quite follow. ``file.txt`` litterally contains lines like I have posted, and so does ``match.txt``.

Comment: The specific approach you're asking for is very needlessly inefficient. Is there a reason you want to do a `grep` at every line (thus making your performance `O(n*m)`, rather than a single join operation, or storing the contents of `match.txt` in an associative array and doing an O(1) lookup, or picking yet another reasonable and sane approach?

Comment: If you're hiding details, those details are relevant to choosing the best algorithm for the task -- if we knew what they were, we could be helping you choose an approach that's reasonable *in light of the details*.

Comment: BTW, your argument as to "why join isn't an option" doesn't actually preclude use of `join`. There's a reason `join` has field support -- put the source file in a field other the one you're joining on, and there you are.

Comment: a seven point specification for output should be reduced to actual required output based on your two inputs. Good luck

Comment: Paraphrasing the asker: "I want to ask a Question. I provide a broken answer. Please help me infer the real question, and give the real answer. As you insist on a proper question, I provided a pseudo code of the broken answer."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have omitted a lot of details, but with the details you *have* provided, we can sketch something like

```
awk 'NR==FNR { w[++n] = $0; next }
    { m=0; for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) if ($0 ~ w[i]) { m=i; break } }
    m && /food/ && /something/ && /whatever/ { k[m]++ }
    END { for(i=1; i<=n; ++i)
        print "%s %s\n", w[i], (k[i] ? "matches" : "does not match") 
        }' file.txt /some/directory/match.txt
```

We read the first file into the array `w` (the expression `NR==FNR` is true while you are reading the first input file).  Then, in the second file, we check whether any word in `w` matches; if so, we check if the same input line also matches `food` and `something` and `whatever` and if so, we mark it as having matched by setting its value in the array `k`. Finally, at the end, we loop over `w` and `k` in parallel, and check whether the current word in `w` is also in `k`.

If you really only care about whether those words match, it would be more efficient to remove matched expressions, and quit when you no longer have any expressions which have not matched; @joepd's script does something like that.  Merging the two should not be hard.

The real lesson here is that if you have more than approximately two `grep`s in a pipeline (and often, more than one, or a mix of `grep` and `sed` or Awk) you should be thinking about refactoring into an Awk (or Perl, or Python, or what have you) helper script.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to use `while` loop to go through each line in `file.txt` and then check if that line matches something in `match.txt`? Something like this should work:

```
while read -r line; do
    if grep -q "${line}" match.txt; then
        echo "${line} matches"
    else
        echo "${line} does not match"
    fi
done < <(cat file.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Barring any concrete example of what you want to see, this might already partially suit your needs:

```
grep -owhf file.txt match.txt
```

This would be closer to what you seem to ask for:

```
awk '
    FNR==NR{a[$1]}
    FNR!=NR{
        for (re in a){
            if ($0~re){
                print re, "matches"
                delete a[re]
            }
        }
    }
    END{
        for (re in a){
            print re, "does not match"
        }
    }
' file.txt match.txt
```

Comment: The thing is, I can't just compare the two file with grep like your first example; I have an extensive chain of grep'ing going on. Also, I want to compare all lines in a file with all lines in another file.

Comment: Excellent. And what is the result that you expect? If you could indicate how the result of the `awk` command differs from what you expect, that would be greatly appreciated.